# angular 2, unable to add underscore.js, 404 not found

Tags: angular, underscore.js

I am trying to add underscore.js library in my angular 2 project.
I have installed it using npm, and i added the script tag for underscore.js in my index.html too but it still showing me this error in console " GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js  " with status 404.

Thanks in advance.

[*** Project Folder Structure Image here ***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnygy.png)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ProjectEx</title>
  <link href="assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="node_modules/underscore/underscore.js"></script>

  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular-cli , you need to include in `.angular-cli.json` . `node_modules` folder is not available in the build.

```
scripts: [
'../node_modules/underscore/underscore.js'
]
```

Comment: yes i do have a .angular-cli.json file in my project and i have already added that in script but its still not working.

Comment: You don't need to include in index.html . It should be available in the code. How do you know it's not available

Comment: i thought the problem was in index.html but found the problem in the pagination component html file. Anyway thank you skeptor.